# [tag:development], what's it for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a good number of questions tagged [development](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development). I don't really get what it's for. The tag wiki explains

> Use this tag for questions regarding the development of open projects.

So what are we talking about? About software development? business development? project development? Any kind of development?

I don't know, which means it's already unclear.

If it's any kind of development, then I think it's too broad. If it's software development, I don't think it offers much over what [software](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) offers, and is still pretty broad; are we talking about software development in general using open source tools and/or materials, or are we talking about developing open source software?

Comment: Pun not included? How could this be! (I'm not a good pun maker, but how about "Removing [development]s in the development tag?"

Answer (score 6):

The [extended tag wiki](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/tags/development/info) gives us a little more information:

> The development of open projects must take into account a number of things, including financial and human resources.

I'm thinking this tag was created with regards to the *overall* development of open projects - including all of the aspects you mention above and possibly some others.

However, as a question classifier that's not very helpful, because its scope is *so* big. Tags *are* supposed to have wide scope, but overly wide scope results in a tag that doesn't do anything for the question and may as well not be there.

**Action:** I'd review the questions with the tag on and change it to other things as necessary: [software-development](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development), [business](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business), [finance](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance), [project-management](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) etc. That should result in its removal.

Comment: Note that [tag:project-management] also exists

Comment: I think I would add [documentation], and maybe [file-structures]

Answer (score 1):

The tag is unclear and useless, burninate it.

Comment: I'd say yes, as long as we review the questions and evaluate whether they could benefit from a different tag such as those I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score -5):

The tag should be used for development of open source software, rename it to [software-development](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development)

Comment: No: as you say in the question, I don't think [software-development] would give us much that [software] doesn't already.